# Installing Python MNE

Tags: python, error-handling, terminal, installation

I'm having a hard time installing python mne. The instructions on their website (https://www.martinos.org/mne/stable/install_mne_python.html) are very straight forward, yet when I run the lines to install the program I get errors I don't know how to interpret. I figured running the macOS only line would fix the problem, but generates another error. I currently have PyQT5.10.1 installed...

```
Zacharys-MacBook-Pro:~ zacharystow$ curl -O 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mne-tools/mne- 
python/master/environment.yml
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  
Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  
Speed
100   659  100   659    0     0   2561      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:- 
-:--  2955

Zacharys-MacBook-Pro:~ zacharystow$ conda env create -f 
environment.yml
Using Anaconda API: https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata ...........


NoPackagesFoundError: Package missing in current osx-64 channels: 
- pyqt >=5.9


Zacharys-MacBook-Pro:~ zacharystow$ pip install --upgrade pyqt5>=5.10
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt5 (from 
versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyqt5
```

Comment: looking at their install instructions, you're missing the `source` command, which will enter the virtual environment it creates called `mne` before the additional mac-only `pip install`.

Comment: This what I get when I run the last command:
(Canopy 64bit) Zacharys-MacBook-Pro:~ zacharystow$ pip install --upgrade 
pyqt5>=5.10
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt5 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyqt5

Comment: There is no pyqt5 5.10, the latest at time of writing is 5.6

Comment: I tried `pip install --upgrade pyqt5.6` and i go the same error

Comment: Zach, there isn't any magic happening here, the error message isn't lying to you: there is no "pyqt5.6" package. Pip installs packages from Pypi, including this one. You can go to Pypi and confirm this yourself. Specifying a version is optional as well, so once you figure out the actual name of the package you are trying to install (hint: read my previous answer more closely) you can leave it off